# How to call launch android messenger app from browser

Tags: php, android

How can I launch Android messenger app from browser?

Comment: I have 2 questions. Is the messaging app made by you? That is, is the messaging app your own. Second is the browser an external browser or you are using a WebView?

Comment: I want to launch google messenger app from chrome or other browser

Answer (score 0):

yes u can call another app from ur browser by using intent filter and data scheme  in the manifest file
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)